# Why keeps pid in char giving always 0?

Tags: c, fork

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct mystruct {
  char string[3];
  char pid
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct mystruct info;
  info.pid = fork();
  strcpy(info.string, "Son");
  if (info.pid == 0)
    printf("%s", info.string);
  else
    printf("Father");
  return 0;
}
```

this code prints

```
Son
Son
```

i would like to know why.

Comment: If you're doing some weird thing (assigning a value of some larger type to a char), a good place to start debugging is to discover if the weird thing is the cause of the unexpected behavior. Printing out the pid (as a pid_t) and its value when truncated is what I'd try first.

Answer (score 7):

The string `"Son"` requires 4 bytes because of the terminating null byte.  But `info.string` only has space for 3 bytes, so you overrun it, causing undefined behavior.  Most likely the null byte overwrites `info.pid` with 0 since that is probably the next byte in memory.

Anyway, don't try to store the result of `fork()` in a `char`.  It returns a `pid_t` and that's the type you should use.  It is likely to overflow a `char`.  If the returned pid happens to be a multiple of 256, your code would erroneously think both processes were the child.

Answer (score 1):

This should work as you expect, look at the alteration insisde `struct mystruct`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct mystruct {
  char string[4]; //<- Need 4 instead of 3 because of the terminating null byte
  pid_t pid;      //<- fork() return pid_t
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  struct mystruct info;
  info.pid = fork();
  strcpy(info.string, "Son");
  if (info.pid == 0)
    printf("%s\n", info.string);
  else
    printf("Father\n");
  return 0;
}
```